# How to resolve IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm new to python and I'm trying to do an assignment for unit but I can't seem to get past an index error. I've tried everything I can think of and anything I could find on the internet but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here is the code I'm trying to get to work.

Both files are in the same folder.

The error message keeps coming up on "hn.append(row[1])"

```
import numpy as np    
import csv           
#import the ploting library bits
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D   # for our 3-D plots
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

lr = []    
hn = []
ac = []

with open("vert.csv") as csvDataFile:   
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)  
    for row in csvReader:
        lr.append(row[0])
        hn.append(row[1])
        ac.append(row[2])

x = np.asfarray(lr[1:])
y = np.asfarray(hn[1:])
z = np.asfarray(ac[1:])*100   

ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')    # plot the x,y,z, data points

ax.set_ylabel('LR')    # axis labels
ax.set_xlabel('NH')
ax.set_zlabel('Performance')

plt.show()
```

Here is the full error message

```
        IndexError                                
        Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-35-0752ace9229f> in <module>
        19     for row in csvReader:
        20         lr.append(row[0])
        ---> 21         hn.append(row[1])
        22         ac.append(row[2])
        23 

        IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Seems like csv reader  read less than you think and the `row` variable is only valid for index 0 but not 1 anymore.

Comment: Check if the csv file has atleast 3 columns

Comment: Thanks for the help!
My file has 4 columns in it but now that I changed the index to 0 I get a 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' "cells": ['

Comment: I would add a `print(row)` right after `for row in csvReader:`.  That way I have a clear(er) idea of what the reader has given me.  Is it really a list of at least 3 elements?  Are those elements strings or numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you've resolved the `IndexError` by ensuring you have at least 3 columns in your CSV file, to overcome the `ValueError`, get `lr`, `hn`, and, `ac` converted to floats. They are currently strings whereas you need float or integers for your plots:

```
lr1 = [float(x) for x in lr] #create a list lr1 with same elements as lr but elements type is float, using list comprehension
hn1 = [float(y) for y in hn] # same operation for hn
ac1 = [float(x) for x in ac] # same operation for ac
x = np.asfarray(lr1[1:])
y = np.asfarray(hn1[1:])
z = np.asfarray(ac1[1:])*100
```